# How to add a keyboard shortcut for AMS multi-line environment in LyX

Tags: lyx, amsmath, keyboard

I use the AMS multi-line environment a lot for homework, and I would like it to replace the regular math environment.

I use LyX, 3.2.2.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Which multi-line environment do you want?  There are several -- `align`, `gather`, `multlined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *LyX* function `math-mutate align` to change any math environment into an *AMS* align one (see *Help>Lyx Functions* for the full list of functions).

To implement this by changing the action of the shortcut, go to *Tools>Preferences>Editing>Shortcuts*, find the shortcut that you currently use to open a math environment (the command will probably be `math-display`), double-click it and change the function to `command-sequence math-display; math-mutate align;`, OK and save. Note `command-sequence` just allows you to chain multiple functions together.

If this isn't exactly what you want, I'm sure you get the idea!